# Most used Java code convention / style guide

Tags: java, coding-style, conventions

I've seen several questions on SO asking about the best coding conventions for Java, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507142/most-authoritative-reference-for-java-code-conventions?lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581231/resources-for-java-coding-style?lq=1), but questions tend to focus on the **most official** Java coding conventions, rather than what the **most used** Java coding convention is. I think the most used style guide would be best to know as an individual programmer, but obviously how widespread a convention is should be balanced against how effective or up to date it is.

Can anyone tell me the most widely used code conventions for Java? Any references to quantitative evidence would be very helpful, but experience from working with others and an idea of what might become the standard in the future would be useful too. It would also be informative if any recommendation was balanced against the drawbacks of that style (e.g. the Oracle conventions no longer being updated).

I've assumed that it's best to follow a single guide so there's no confusion and anyone that joins on a project can just be given a link to the guide. This question is for programmers that are not part of a company with it's own style guide; it is for individual programmers that may work on collaborative projects where contributors should use the same style.

**Edit:** just to be clear, I am aware of the different style guides available. I'd like information from more experienced people as to which guidelines are most followed, and whether frequency of use is enough to justify using them, or whether they have other drawbacks that mean they should be ignored despite their popularity.

Comment: [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html)

Comment: you can check out google's convention as well

Comment: Duplication of my comment answered under thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/49970437/2235085

Answer (score 1):

Which convention is more used is hard to say, and I dont think that you would get this information from anywhere. Even if you got it, would probabbly specific to a context or region.

My advice if you want something "official" and with a big name behind it, or a book, in the case that you need to justify this choice to someone else, I would say: [Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882).

There are a lot of people out there that follow the conventions of that book, and the book itself is writen with Java code examples. I think that's your best choice. :)

The Agile and Software Craftsmanship movement tend to follow someway or another much of the principles of that book (the later even more).